# my kubernetes cluster is down after reboot

Tags: kubernetes, bare-metal-server

After every reboot my kubernetes cluster does not work fine and I get

```
The connection to the server 192.168.1.4:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I have 4 ubuntu on **baremetal** one of them is master and 3 worker and I **turned off swap and disabled it**.
and I read somewhere I should run this command two solve it

```
sudo -i
swapoff -a
exit
strace -eopenat kubectl version
```

and it is work.
But why this was happening?

Comment: check if `kubelet` & `docker` are up and running on each node...

Comment: @yasinlachini is it still actual? did you manage to fix it? any errors in kubelet logs?

Comment: I have not rebooted it after i reboot it and get error i post my log

Comment: Yasin jan, I have added a new answer which has happened to me recently. I hope it works. I would be thankful if you could accept my answer in case it is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

First please run `systemctl status kubelet` and verify if the service is running: 
"*Active: active (running)*"
Disable swap:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo sed -i '/ swap / s/^\(.*\)$/#\1/g' /etc/fstab
```

verify all reference found in **/etc/fstab** about swap.

Please perform also post "kubeadm init" steps for current user as described here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

After reboot please check:
`systemctl status docker`
enable docker at startup if it's not working
`systemctl enable docker`

You can also verify kubelet status:

```
systemctl status kubelet
systemctl enable kubelet
```

take a look for any errors:

```
journalctl -u kubelet.service
journalctl
```

And please share with your findings.

Comment: i write it blod that i turn it off and disable it

Comment: of course i run those command if i do not run them the kubernetes does not work

Comment: Hi Yasin, answer was updated about kubelet and docker status.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that Kubelet is not getting restarted. You need to check Kubelet logs correct the issues if any.

Check docker driver and the driver used by kubelet should be same.

Swap should be disabled, and so on

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you install the cluster.

In this post, I will mention the possible ways to resolve this problem.

1. Make sure the swap is off.

   ```
   swapoff -a
   ```
2. Check the state of Kubelet. In case it is exited and can't work properly, you can check the log of it.

   ```bash
   journalctl -xfu kubelet.service
   ```

   In my case the log wasn't that helpful. I was trying to see the log of other components. After searching and try to find a clue, I have found that there is an error with ‍`cri-dockerd` service, because it may not be enabled in systemd.

   ```bash
   systemctl start cri-dockerd.service
   systemctl enable cri-dockerd.service
   ```

   Finally restart the kubelet service and check its status:

   ```bash
   systemctl restart kubelet.service
   systemctl status kubelet.service
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs most probably when swap is turned ON and KUBECONFIG variable is lost due to VM restart. Simply follow below steps to resolve the issue:

```
swapoff -a (Turn the swap off) - The kubelet doesn't work when the swap is ON.
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config - Export kubeconfig variable of Kubernetes.
```

Now run:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

Eventually, the cluster & pods will take some time to recover, they might give *Unknown-status* at first but then after 5-10 mins it will come in *Running* state.